# How can I parse Azure Blob URI in nodejs/javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to parse Azure Blob URI in nodejs and extract storage account name, container name and blob name.

I investigated both [azure-sdk-for-node](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/index.html) and [azure-storage-node](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/) but I found no method for doing so.

In case Blob URI is invalid, I would also like to detect that, so probably regex (if possible) would be a good way to go.

Some examples of Blob URI:

1. `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob`
2. `http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/myblob`
3. `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/$root/myblob`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the [specification from Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata), I came up with following function ([gist](https://gist.github.com/Martinsos/34d962b81b01082a45d90b2af5988097)) that uses regex to parse the blob uri and it also throws an error if blob uri is invalid.

Storage account name and container name should be completely right/precise, only blob name I left somewhat loose since it is more complex to define.

```
/**
 * Validates and parses given blob uri and returns storage account, 
 * container and blob names.
 * @param {string} blobUri - Valid Azure storage blob uri.
 * @returns {Object} With following properties:
 *   - {string} storageAccountName
 *   - {string} containerName
 *   - {string} blobName
 * @throws {Error} If blobUri is not valid blob uri.
 */
const parseAzureBlobUri = (blobUri) => {
  const ERROR_MSG_GENERIC = 'Invalid blob uri.'

  const storageAccountRegex = new RegExp('[a-z0-9]{3,24}')
  const containerRegex = new RegExp('[a-z0-9](?!.*--)[a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]')
  const blobRegex = new RegExp('.{1,1024}')  // TODO: Consider making this one more precise.
  const blobUriRegex = new RegExp(
    `^http[s]?:\/\/(${ storageAccountRegex.source })\.blob.core.windows.net\/`
    + `(?:(\$root|(?:${ containerRegex.source }))\/)?(${ blobRegex.source })$`
  )
  const match = blobUriRegex.exec(blobUri)
  if (!match) throw Error(ERROR_MSG_GENERIC)

  return {
    storageAccountName: match[1],
    // If not specified, then it is implicitly root container with name $root.
    containerName: match[2] || '$root',
    blobName: match[3]
  }
}
```

Comment: @Thomas would you mind elaborating? Which url parser, and how is that a better match for this problem?

Comment: There is default url parser for nodejs (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html) so you can get the hostname, path etc easily. You don't have to maintain your own piece of code. Also regex are not parser, the complexity of regex can have a cost (performance)

Comment: @Thomas thanks, I did not know about url parser for nodejs, but it does not seem to be a match for what I need. I want to 1. validate blob uri and 2. extract storage account, container and blob names from it. How could I do this with the nodejs url parser? Maybe I am missing something - would you mind providing an example?

Comment: I've added an answer, hope it could be helful

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`url.parse`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html).

Main reason for me is to avoid using regular expression and it is also easier to understand, read and modify.

Here is a sample code:

```
const url = require('url')

const parseAzureBlobUri = (blobUrl) => {
    let uri = url.parse(blobUrl)

    // Extract the storage account name
    let storageAccountName = uri.hostname.split('.')[0]        

    // Remove the 1st trailing slash then extract segments
    let segments = uri.pathname.substring(1).split('/')

    // If only one segment, this is the blob name
    if(segments.length === 1){
        return {
            storageAccountName,
            containerName: '$root',
            blobName: segments[0]
        }
    }

    // get the container name
    let containerName = segments[0]

    // Remove the containername from the segments
    segments.shift()

    return {
        storageAccountName,
        containerName,
        blobName: segments.join('/')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the type of solution not using regexes!
Unfortunately, this kind of solution does not do much regarding validation, I am guessing for that you would use regexes again.
Also, personally, I find solution with regexes to be easier to read and understand, but that is due to personal preferences and how comfortable one is with regexes I guess.

Comment: Yeah I guess it is a different approcach, both are valid